# jQuery toggle not triggering css animation?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I’ve made a little toggle button which you click and it opens up a hidden menu, whilst rotating a cross.

I’ve got the cross to rotate using css animation and the sub menu appears, but i need it to animate slide out nicely rather than just appearing. The going from display none, to display block doesn’t seem to animate with css, is there anyway round this?

Or does css animation not work on the display style?

I’ve a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c8qryrze/5/)

```
<nav class="filter_nav inner">
    <ul class="subnav">
        <li>Text</li>
         <li>Text</li>
         <li>Text</li>
         <li>Text</li>
         <li>Text</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="toggleNavOuter">
        <li class="toggleNavButton">+</li> 
        <li>Filter</li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

JS here..

```
    $(function(){
     $(".toggleNavOuter").click(function () {
        $(".subnav").toggleClass("active");
        $(".toggleNavOuter").toggleClass("active");
        $(".toggleNavButton").toggleClass("active");
     });
    });
```

Comment: Hope there is no flaw in your fiddle. `onclick` function works great what is your problem.

Comment: Cross rotates. For showing/hiding animation you can try [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) with setting duration.

Comment: You can't add transition to display :) Try using width and opacity instead, you can't animate from display none to block using css3 transitions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't animate `display` property what you need is to animate the `width`.

- One option can be this: Add `width:0` instead of `display:none`

  ```
   .filter_nav .subnav {
       width:0;
       transition: width 0.8s ease-in-out 0s;
   }
  ```

  And then on `active` place some fixed width:

  ```
   .filter_nav .subnav.active {
       width:300px;
   }
  ```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8qryrze/7/)

Comment: Thank you, i didn’t realise you couldn’t animate the display property, they should change that. Thank you for everyones help.

Comment: Np @user4630 glad to help...remeber you can also animate width with jquery if you want some dynamic width you can also use jquery to calculate the value.